# Web Map Server (geoserver) on CentOS 6

Tags: geoserver, installation, linux

I am trying to setup a web map server on a CentOS 6.2 virtual machine for development.  I have never used Linux or web mapping frameworks, but I am trying to do this work as low cost as possible.  So far, I am having some difficulty determining how to install and configure all the packages I need.

Here are the packages I want to install:

Apache Web Server
Apache Tomcat? - is this necessary?
Geoserver
PostgreSQL/PostGIS
GeoExt?
Mapfish?

Has anyone had any experience with these packages in a Linux server?  Could you provide any advice or links for setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a painless installation, you might want to try the OpenGeo Suite. It comes with preconfigured and integrated GeoServer and PostGIS.

First, add the repos:
For 32-bit systems:

```
 cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://yum.opengeo.org/centos/5/i386/OpenGeo.repo
```

for 64 bit systems:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://yum.opengeo.org/centos/5/x86_64/OpenGeo.repo
```

Update yum:

```
yum update
```

You can then install the OpenGeo Suite by typing:

```
yum install opengeo-suite
```

Once the installation has completed, you can go to the dashboard by navigating to:

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboard/
```

Comment: Thanks @R.K. - is the OpenGeo Suite community edition licensed for commercial purposes?

Comment: It is licensed under the GPL so you may use it however way you want as long as you comply with the GPL. http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2008/compliance-guide.html

Comment: Downvoting as the repo has been shut down.  You can download the OpenGeo suite at the Boundless site after registration.  It's still free for unsupported use as far as I'm aware. http://www.boundlessgeo.com

Comment: @minus34 It was an answer to a question from another time. Repos do get shut down. I do wish you gave me the chance to update it before downvoting the answer though.

Answer (score 4):

the quickest way to run GeoServer is:

- install java in your linux machine, using prepared RPM packages o "by hand" if you prefer. Use "java -version" to check you have the Oracle java version, not the opensource one.
- from here http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Stable download the binary independent package
- uncompress, move into geoserver folder and execute: "java -jar start.jar".

You also can use the geoserver/bin/startup.sh script.

I usually edit it and add this line:
    export GEOSERVER_HOME=/opt/software/geoserver-2.1.3/bin

to ensure the GEOSERVER_HOME environment variable is defined.

With this you will have a basic installation only fine for development (not production) environment.
In addition you can install Postgres+PostGIS if you want to use a spatial DB to store features but it is not requried by geoserver.

Comment: Thanks @neil.  This is a development machine, but my hope is that once I set it up and get my web map application running, I would like to copy the virtual machine to the production server.  What would be difference about this installation for production?

Comment: For production you can install too the JAI libraries for better raster performance and increase some Tomcat parameters (like memory).